# What is the target framework moniker for unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, multitargeting

Recently we developed a multi-targeted .net library in which We have added the support for UWP, .NetCore, .NetStandard, Xamarion.IOS and MonoDroid by using below property

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid90;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

We try to extend the support for an unity project, But we down't know what is tfm for unity, When i search for it I came across the term NET 4.x But I don't know how to use it as tfm in TargetFrameworks tag, Can anyone else help me find it out.

Comment: Not confident enough to post it as an answer but I think it is "netstandard2.0"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019#choosing-between-net-4x-and-net-standard-20-profiles .NET Standard 2.0 should be your primary option, but you can choose net4xx (likely net471) if you really need a bigger API surface.